# Selecting max in linq query or rewriting to method chain syntax

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I managed to turn this SQL query:

```
SELECT c.carId, c.Codename, count(c.CarId) as [CarCount],
  FROM [DbEfTesting].[dbo].[Cars] c
  left join Accessories a on c.CarId = a.CarId
  left join CarsPeople cp on cp.CarId = c.CarId
  left join People p on cp.PersonId = p.PersonId
  group by c.CarId, c.Codename
```

into a LINQ query:

```
var x = from c in _context.Cars
    join a in _context.Accessories on c.CarId equals a.Car.CarId
    join j in _context.CarsPeople on c.CarId equals j.CarId
    join p in _context.People on j.PersonId equals p.PersonId
    group c by new { c.CarId, c.Codename } into g
    select new VMCarAggregate()
    {
        CarId = g.Key.CarId,
        Codename = g.Key.Codename,
        CarCount = g.Count()
    };
```

But now I'm lost trying to include a max value e.g the SQL:

```
SELECT c.carId, c.Codename, count(c.CarId) as [CarCount], max(a.AccessoryId) ...
```

I googled it and found lots of answers for method syntax. If I were using method chain syntax, I know I could do something like this:

```
_context.Accessories.Max(a => a.AccessoryId);
```

but I can't figure out how to do the `group by` in method chain syntax so either:

**How can I convert that query to method syntax?**

or

**How can I inject a select on the max a.AccessoryId in the LINQ query format?**

Comment: Do you want it in your `VMCarAggregate` projection ?

Comment: I have a new `VMCarAggregateWithMax` viewmodel but essentially yes, it would need to be in the view result.

Comment: when you are not selecting any column from the other tables `Accessories`, `CarsPeople`, `People` , why do you have to join them?

Comment: They're joined because they will affect the `CarCount` column. e.g. BlueCar has two accessories and two people, but if I don't join with people then I only get 2 count instead of 2*2=4. The count is to signify all records that will be shown when a user explodes the data - there will be 4 rows shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code once:

```
var x = from c in _context.Cars
                    join a in _context.Accessories equals a.Car.CarId
                    join j in _context.CarsPeople on c.CarId equals j.CarId
                    join p in _context.People on j.PersonId equals p.PersonId
                    group new { c.CarId, c.Codename, a.AccesoryId } by new { c.CarId, c.Codename } into g
                    select new
                    {
                        CarId = g.Key.CarId,
                        Codename = g.Key.Codename,
                        CarCount = g.Count(),
                        MaxAccesory = g.Max(z => z.AccesoryId)
                    };
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly. It was the `group new { } by new  { }` I had no idea how to work.